# Prolog term concatenation

Tags: prolog, concatenation

I'm trying to format a result from a program but getting an hard time.

I wanted to give something like this as result:

```
Res = do(paint(x) do(clean(a), do(repair(b) , initialState)))
```

basically, I want to concatenate successive terms to initialState atom but, it doesn't work with atom_concat since the other terms to concatenate aren't atoms and also I wanted to add the ) everytime I pass through the "do" function.

So it would be something like: Res = initialState.

When do function was called, I would have a function like

```
concatenateTerm(Pred, Res, Res).
```

Pred beeing repair(b) for instance and obtain the result: `res = do(repair(b),` initialState).

Is this possible to be done?

Thanks

Comment: Probably I don't understand you, but... I presume you mean `concatenateTerm(Pred,Res,ResNext)`. In that case define it as `concatenateTerm(A, B, do(A, B)).`.

Comment: but concatenateterm wouldnt give me res as a result. 
I could do Temp = Res and then call concatenateTerm (Pred,Temp, Res), which would concatenate Pred with Temp and give the result on Res but yet again, it doesn't work with atom_concat since it fails with non atomic terms.

and also it wouldn't add the ) at the end.

Comment: You wish to build up a complicated term from simpler ones?

Comment: atoms is something that is logically can't be devided into smaller pieces (that's why "atom"). I.e. if you have `Steel = combine(carbon, coal)` you can get elements out of term `combine(carbon,coal)` by `combine(X, Y) = Steel`, but you can't get anything out of term `carbon` because that's *atom*. The only thing you can do with atoms is to to try unify them with variables (there is rules `atom_chars`, but they are "special").

Comment: Sorry I missed the comment to my answer, I have commented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to do something like:

```
Res0 = initialState,
do(repair(b), Res0, Res1),
do(clean(a), Res1, Res2),
do(paint(x), Res2, Res3),
```

where you final result is in `Res3`. Remember prolog procedures don't "return" anything and input and output values must be passed through arguments.

Why do you want to concatenate successive terms to the *atom* `initialState`? Thi is not the prolog way. It would be much more natural in prolog to build a structure which is modified each time.

Comment: As well as prolog doesn't "return" it also doesn't "modify" (except special cases related with dynamic predicates, but replacing some predicates is also a bad approach). The only thing that can look as "modifying" (but actually is not) is using partially-bound variables, parts of which is bound at some steps to probably another partially-bound variable (ex. `Res3 = do(paint(x), Res2), Res2 = do(clean(a), Res1), Res1 = do(repair(b), Res0), Res0 = initialState` or `member((red=blue),X), member((blue=red),X)`). But anyway in your example you have no *concatenation* of terms, only call to `do/3`

Comment: @ony Sorry missed this. Of course there is concatenation of terms. When `do/3` does anything it adds more information to its "input" term, the second argument and "returns" it by binding it to its third argument. So the value bound to `Res0` is modified and bound to `Res1` which is then modified and bound to `Res2` which is modified and bound to `Res3`. This *chaining* of data through variables is common in Prolog and the variable naming indicates this. `Res0` -> `Res1` -> `Res2` -> `Res3`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @rvirding in that you may just need to construct a PROLOG *term* as your result, instead of trying to construct an *atom*. Even if you attempt the latter (which is indeed possible), you can usually convert from atoms to terms and back again using utility functions (such as [`atom_to_term/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_to_term/3) or [`term_to_atom/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_to_atom/2) in SWI-PROLOG), if need be.

Anyway, a simple predicate to take a whole list of your 'state' terms and output such a term as you've described earlier could look like this:

```
build_do_term([X,Y], do(X,Y)) :- !.
build_do_term([X|Xs], do(X,Rem)) :-
    build_do_term(Xs, Rem).
```

Calling this predicate on the state terms (of which there must be at least two):

```
?- build_do_term([paint(x), clean(a), repair(b), initialState], Rem).
Rem = do(paint(x), do(clean(a), do(repair(b), initialState))).
```

...which reflects the behaviour you've described as being after. If you don't want to build the term all at once from a list, you can still use the `do/2` term construction method as used in `build_do_term/2` above in your own code to construct the appropriate `do/2` term as necessary.

Comment: how did you guessed that @d0pe already *concatenated* terms in list `[paint(x) | [clean(a) | [... |[]]..]` which is exactly the same problem as *concatenation* with `do/2`?

Comment: I wasn't guessing or assuming anything about the code @d0pe is working with. The purpose of using the list structure here as input to `build_do_term/2` is to illustrate, in a simple manner, how a PROLOG predicate could be implemented to construct the (supposedly) necessary `do/2` term, as described, as a guide, since d0pe wanted something like `concatenateTerm/3`. I think this is clear from my last statement in the post... :-\

Answer (score -1):

@d0pe, there is no results in prolog (they exists in Mercury and Erlang, I guess) there is only named values which specified/unified in head and probably unified later in body. Doing `Temp = Res, concatenateTerm (Pred,Temp, Res)` will fail in most cases because `Temp = Res, Res = do(Pred, Temp)` will produce infinitely recursive term `do(Pred, do(Pred, do(Pred, ...)))` (when appropriate extension is available). I guess that this isn't what you want.
But now I understand that you want to *modify* `Res` - that's incorrect understanding of Prolog. There is no variables, you should use next approach `Res0 = initialState, Res1 = do(repair(b), Res0), Res2 = do(clean(a), Res1), Res3 = do(paint(x), Res2).`

Probably your rule will look something like (see examples of monkey+bananna in prolog):

```
solve(FinalState, finish, FinalState). % our initial state is our goal

solve(InitState, do(Action, Future), FinalState):-
  action(InitState, Action, NewState),
  solve(NewState, Future, FinalState).
```

Comment: I believe @d0pe just asked how to _construct a term_ to _format some output_... why are you (rather confusingly) talking about infinitely recursive terms and modifying bound variables?

Comment: @rati, and I did respoinded how to *construct a term*. recursive terms and modifying bound variables is mentioned because of "So it would be something like:" and `Res = initialState, concatenateTerm(Pred, Res, Res), Pred = repair(b)` and expecting `Res = do(repair(b), initialState)` which is looks like @d0pe thing that concatenateTerm should take "first" `Res` concatenate `repair(b)` to it and return it as "second" `Res`.